# Access Array of Objects after filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, filter

so I have a JSON object returned from a webservice. Now I want to:

- get a subset which matches a categoryTitle i pass as parameter (this seems to work)
- from my filtered resultset I want to get another array of objects (helpsubjects), and for each of this subjects I want to extract the SubjectTitle.

Problem: It seems my Array of HelpSubjects does not exist, but I can't figure out why and hope you could help.

Perhaps this piece of commented code makes it more clear:

```
$.fn.helpTopicMenu = function (data) {
    that = this;

    var categoryContent = contents.filter(function (el) {
        return el.CategoryTitle == data.categoryTitle;
    });

    debug('categorys Content: ', categoryContent); //see below

    var container = $('#subjectList');
    var subjectList = categoryContent.HelpSubjects;
    debug('Subjects in Category: ', subjectList); // UNDEFINED?!

    $.each(subjectList, function (i, item) {
        container.append(
            $('<li><a href=\"#\"></a></li>').html(subjectList[i].SubjectTitle)
        );
    });
```

the line `debug('categorys Content: ', categoryContent);` returns the following object as shown in the picutre (sadly I can't add a picture directly to the post yet, so here's the link): https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kKWx.png

so as I understand it, there IS actually a HelpSubjects-Array, each entry containing a SubjectTitle (in the picture there actually is only one entry, but I need to have the `Artikel einfügen` as my html.

Would be great if you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `categoryContent` set is an array of objects.

Try debugging `categoryContent[0].HelpSubjects` and see if you can access the property. If so, you can also loop this array if need be.

Comment: argh! yeh, that was my fault. Thank you so much, had a knot in my brain! I'll accept the answer in a few minutes (can'T do it yet, don't know why)